# Minimum of Maximum Difference Between Two Elements of A Subsequence

Tags: arrays, algorithm, subsequence

For any subsequence in a given array, the following quantity is defined as D.
**D(S) = max(|S[i]-S[j]|)** for all 1<=i<=j<=|S|.
d is a given quantity.
the array is given.
we are also given p.

**Task : I have to check whether a subsequence of size p exists for which D < d. i.e Among all the subsequences of size p, is there a subsequence whose D < d. **

My approach :
Begin at the starting of the array. Keep 4 quantities with you : maximum positive element, minimum positive element, maximum negative element (based on absolute value), minimum negative element( based on absolute value),  . Check whether the current element A[i] gives difference less than d when subtracted from the four values.
If yes then :
Increase the count variable. The count variable keeps a count of the elements of subseqeucne which give difference < d.

Basically I am trying to create a subsequence that has D < d.

To do this I applied the following code:

```
bool isPossible(lli A[],lli n, 
               lli p, lli d) 
{   
   lli count = 1; 
   lli last_position = A[0]; 
   int min = A[0];
   int max = A[0];
   int maxneg = A[0];
   int minneg = A[0];
    for (lli i = 1; i < n; i++) { 
        if ((abs(A[i]-max) < d) && (abs(A[i]-min) < d) &&  (abs(A[i]-minneg) < d) && (abs(A[i]-maxneg) < d) ){ 
            last_position = A[i];
            count++; 
            if (count == p) { 
                return false; 
            } 

        if(A[i]>max){
        max = A[i];
        }

        if(A[i]<min){
            min = A[i];
        }

        if((A[i]<0 && abs(A[i])>abs(maxneg)) || (A[i]<0 && maxneg >0)){
        maxneg = A[i];
        }

         if((A[i]<0 && abs(A[i])<abs(minneg)) || (A[i]<0 && minneg >0)){
        minneg = A[i];
        }

        } 

    } 
    return true; 
}
```

I don't understand why this approach is wrong. I also feel that this is not an elegant approach and involves too many conditional statements.

Comment: "I don't understand why this approach is wrong" You don't tell us why you consider it is wrong. Besides, considering your task, I would expect at least a function that just calculates D(S), given 3 parameters: the array A, the index s of the start of the subseq and the length p of the subseq. From another function, call this function for every subseq of length p (the s param only needs to change). In your loop, compare what it returns to d. Keep any optimization for later (or never). Same for the elegance.

Comment: Ok, I will do that. I told I didn't understand why it's wrong because it wasn't passing testcases on the online judge. It passed one and didn't pass others. All the testcases are hidden (It's a practise problem for my dsa course at college). I will try making a separate function for D(S) and apply it to subsequences and get back. Thank you for the reply!

Comment: Why not simply sorting the arrray, and consider contiguous subsequences of the sorted array ?

Comment: I didn't go with that approach because I thought the in a subsequence the order of elements is important. I was not sure if we sort the array it will work.

Comment: Yes the sorting approach worked! I had been working on it for a day. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @user90596 Good. Please note that if you want to adress a comment to someone in particular, you should use `@Name`

Comment: Oh okay @Damien !